# Delete first characters off of a line in a file with awk or grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I'm attempting to remove a certain pattern from a line, but not the entire line itself. An example would be:

**Original:**

```
user=dannyBoy
```

**Desired:**

```
dannyBoy
```

I have a file that is full of lines like that, so I was wondering how I would be able to cut a specific part of the text off, whether that be just removing the first five characters from the list or searching for the pattern "user=" and removing it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but that is all the file is. My userlog file is just lines like what I listed under original, but more than one (hence why I wanted to see if there was an option to do it for an entire file). I want to remove the characters from the "=" sign and back, the equal sign included in that.

Comment: OK then it makes sense not being able to have something more concrete :) I just posted an answer according to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

```
cut -d'=' -f2- file

sed 's/^[^=]*//' file

awk -F= '{print $2}' file #if just one = is present
```

- `cut` sets a delimiter (`-d'=`) and then prints all the fields starting from the 2nd one (`-f2-`).
- `sed` looks for all the content from the beginning up to the first `=` and removes it.
- `awk` sets `=` as field separator and prints the second field.

Comment: How would I modify the cut command if I were to do it in the other direction? As in, if I was wanting to remove content on the right side as opposed to the left? Say, if I needed to remove a stray punctuation mark.
Thanks for your thorough answer (:

Comment: @Dumpcats you can say `cut -d'=' -f1 file`. With `-f` you indicate the field number you want based on the field separator you indicate with `-d`.

Comment: It worked again (thanks), though I noticed in the second example you omitted the "-" after the -f1 whereas the -f2- has dashes on both sides.

Comment: @Dumpcats you are ignoring 2 dear friends: `google` and `man`.

Comment: @Dumpcats with cut you can specify a single field (like `-f1` for the first field) or a range (like `-f2-`). `2-` means all the fields from the second one to the end, which in this case is not necessary as there are only 2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

The command below deletes the first 5 characters:

```
$ echo "user=dannyboy" | cut -c 6-
```

You can use it on a file with `cut -c 6- inputfilename` as well.

Comment: "...be just removing the first five characters..."  is one of the alternatives OP requested.  The command deletes the first 5 characters.  You can use on a file with `cut -c 6- inputfilename` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ex`:

```
echo user=dannyBoy | ex -s +"norm df=" +%p -cq! /dev/stdin
```

where `ex` is equivalent to `vi -e`/`vim -e` which basically executes vi command: `df=` (delete until finds `=`), then print the buffer (`%p`).

If you've multiple lines like that, then it would be simpler by using substitution:

```
ex -s +"%s/^.*=//g" +%p -cq! foo.txt
```

To edit file in place, change `-cq!` to `-cwq`.